# How to stop images flash in sveltekit

Tags: typescript, sveltekit

When you initially load a website, the images flash when it goes to a different images. However, once the images are cached in the browser, subsequent visits to the website will show the images instantly without any flashing or delays.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {onMount} from "svelte";
    import {writable} from "svelte/store";

    // Define your image URLs here
    const images = [
        {
            path: "https://static.bunnycdn.ru/i/cache/images/5/58/5806a16f2892768b4930c39ebf6ce756.jpg",
            id: "Image 1",
        },
        {
            path: "https://static.bunnycdn.ru/i/cache/images/0/03/0307ce050517b8fde68134b23fa9b1d1.jpg",
            id: "Image 2",
        },
    ];

    let currentIndex = writable(0);

    let interval: ReturnType<typeof setInterval>;

    onMount(() => {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
            currentIndex.update((value) => (value + 1) % images.length);
        }, 3000); // Change slide every 3 seconds
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    });
</script>

<div class="slideshow">
    <div class="list">
        {#each images as image, i (image)}
            <div
                class="item"
                style="position: relative; display: {$currentIndex === i ? 'block' : 'none'};"
            >
                <img
                    class="slide {i === $currentIndex ? 'active' : ''}"
                    src={image.path}
                    alt={`Slide ${i + 1}`}
                />
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
</div>
```

this is small sample code of what i did.

what i want is that when website loads. The images don't flash when going to next images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that currently all images are added to the DOM and start loading at the same time, if there are many, this wastes bandwidth and possibly delays the display of the current image.

You might want to just render the current image instead of using an `#each`.

Also, in the given example there is no reason for `currentIndex` to be a store and for `interval` to be declared outside of `onMount`.

You will always run into the issue of the first image not necessarily being loaded, but for the other ones, you can ensure they are loaded first before advancing to their slide.

E.g. by using the `Image` constructor to load the source. Would use an timeouts instead of an interval, that way if loading takes a very long time, it will not try to switch away prematurely.

```js
onMount(() => {
    const loadImage = item => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.onload = () => resolve();
        image.onerror = () => reject();
        image.src = item.path;
    });

    let timeout;
    let destroyed = false;

    const nextSlide = async () => {
        const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;
        await loadImage(images[nextIndex]); // TODO: handle image load errors?
        currentIndex = nextIndex;

        if (!destroyed) // Because of await - could be destroyed in the meantime
            timeout = setTimeout(nextSlide, 3000);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(nextSlide, 3000);

    return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        destroyed = true;
    };
});
```

(If you need to keep `currentIndex` a store for some reason, you can take the above code and just [use `$currentIndex` instead](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values), no need to call `set()` or `update()` in component code.)

The loaded `Image` could also be directly inserted into the DOM on load, e.g. by making the slide switching functionality an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-action) which is passed the DOM node it is used on.

---

Another approach would be to add `on:load` directly to the `<img>` in the markup, but then it has to somehow interact with the slide timing logic. One could e.g. store a promise on the items and resolve it:

```html
<script>
  // ...

  const deferred = () => {
    let funcs;
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => funcs = { resolve, reject });
    return Object.assign(promise, funcs);
  };

  // might cause SSR issues
  const images = [...].map(x => ({ ...x, loaded: deferred() }));

  let currentIndex = 0;

  onMount(() => {
    let timeout;
    let destroyed = false;
    const nextSlide = async () => {
      const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % images.length;
      await images[nextIndex].loaded;
      currentIndex = nextIndex;

      if (!destroyed) timeout = setTimeout(nextSlide, 3000);
    };
    timeout = setTimeout(nextSlide, 3000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      destroyed = true;
    };
  });
</script>

...
<img ...
     on:load={() => image.loaded.resolve()} />
```

This only works if the next image is already in the DOM, otherwise it would not load.